# What is this GlueList Data Structure?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, lists

I came across a new list data structure called [GlueList](https://github.com/ertugrulcetin/GlueList) that claims faster than classic list implementations.

How does it work ?

How can it be faster than ArrayList and LinkedList ?

Comment: Well, what description to they give? Do you expect us to read the source code for you? Try for yourself and extract a conceptual/algorithmic description of their data structure. Then, try to analyse operation costs. Where and how do you get stucl?